# unload AppDomain

Tags: c#, process, appdomain

A DLL process is running in an isolated App. Domain which was runned from a 3rd application.
I would like to unload AppDomain

If I use Enviroment.Exit(), it also kills the father application (app which lauches the DLL process)

**edit**

Doing as it follows neither:

```
        AppDomain domainObj = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        AppDomain.Unload(domainObj);
```

Comment: "DLL Process" does not make sense. Do you mean AppDomain within another process? If so do you want to unload that AppDomain from within its process or from another process?

Comment: Yes, I want to unload the APP from within its process.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "a dll process" because it does not make a great deal of sense and is the reason I am downvoting this question.

Comment: I did not know how to describe it, that is why I called "dll Process". I would like to stop an Application Domain and I do not know how to do it. I think I have to do it as the other users said. AppDomain.Unload. But How can I get that AppDomain?

Comment: How do you launch this "dll process"

Comment: @PeterRitchie From an released app which allows to lauch DLL creating it in an APP domain

Comment: @kmxillo That doesn't make any sense, what is a "released app", and you don't "launch DLLs" when you create an APP domain.  Creating an app domain and loading a DLL into an app domain doesn't invoke any code--you have to explain how you code is being invoked before anyone can tell you how to terminate it.

Comment: @kmxillo You will need to explain what you're doing correctly. If you are unsure about terminology - just explain what happens in plain words. Also don't assume what the solution is going to be (like unloading an AppDomain), just describe the problem. There might be totally different solutions to your REAL issue.

Comment: @PeterRitchie; @ananthonline: I would like to stop the execution of a dll while is loaded in one application

When the application lauches an exception so  the dll loaded "must be stopped". I am loading/executing the dll from the menu of that application. 

I ve known that the application separed the loaded dll in app domains.

Comment: Still, a dll does not "execute".  Until you detail *how* you're executing code in the DLL, people can only guess at what a solution could be.

Comment: So, it sounds like you're getting a message suggesting a "file is in use".  You need to figure out what application (which is *not* and app domain) is using that file and manually terminate it.

Comment: @PeterRitchie. The app loads the dll from a starting point and the code starts to execute from Main methode. When the exception is called I want to stop the "execution", I want to "interrupt it"

Answer (score 0):

If a function from the DLL is running as a thread in a separate AppDomain in your process, then you can try calling [AppDomain.Unload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload.aspx). According to the documentation,

> When a thread calls Unload, the target domain is marked for unloading. The dedicated thread attempts to unload the domain, and all threads in the domain are aborted. If a thread does not abort, for example because it is executing unmanaged code, or because it is executing a finally block, then after a period of time a CannotUnloadAppDomainException is thrown in the thread that originally called Unload. If the thread that could not be aborted eventually ends, the target domain is not unloaded. Thus, in the .NET Framework version 2.0 domain is not guaranteed to unload, because it might not be possible to terminate executing threads.

So if you are unable to successfully unload this other appdomain - you may have to find other alternatives.